# MySQL join same table twice on same column with different value returning most recent row only

Tags: mysql, join

I'm stuck trying to solve a small part of what is otherwise a complex JOIN.

We have an 'instructions' table and an 'estimates' table. In the 'estimates' we have multiple rows for different types of `estimates` for a given instruction.

Instructions Table

```
id | address | status
1 | 27 TAYLOR ROAD, ALBION PARK NSW 2527 | InProgress
```

Estimates Table

```
id | instruction_id | basis | basis_date | basis_value
1 | 1 | ContractPrice | 2012-04-05 | 124000
2 | 1 | CAMV | 2012-02-01 | 120000
3 | 1 | CustomerEstimate | 2012-06-07 | 132000
4 | 1 | ContractPrice | 2013-01-03 | 140000
5 | 1 | CustomerEstimate | 2013-02-09 | 145000
```

What we want is actually 2 joins of 'instructions' on 'estimates' based on instructions.id = estimates.instruction_id and estimates.basis for 1) the most recent 'CustomerEstimate' (aliasing basis_date and basis_value as estimate_date and estimate_value) and 2) most recent 'ContractPrice' (again, aliasing basis_date and basis_value as contact_date and contract_value).

The intended result would be as follows;

```
id | address | status | contract_price | contract_date | estimate_date | estimate_value
1 | 27 TAYLOR ROAD, ALBION PARK NSW 2527 | InProgress | 2013-01-03 | 140000 | 2013-02-09 | 145000
```

I would really appreciate some assistance from the SQL gurus out there.

Many thanks,
Trent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT i.id,  
       i.address, 
       i.status,
       p.max_date contract_date, 
       p.basis_value contract_price, 
       e.max_date estimate_date, 
       e.basis_value estimate_value
  FROM Instructions i LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT q1.instruction_id, max_date, basis_value
      FROM Estimates e JOIN
    (
        SELECT instruction_id, MAX(basis_date) max_date
          FROM Estimates
         WHERE basis = 'CustomerEstimate'
         GROUP BY instruction_id
    ) q1 ON e.instruction_id = q1.instruction_id AND e.basis_date = q1.max_date
) e ON i.id = e.instruction_id LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT q2.instruction_id, max_date, basis_value
      FROM Estimates e JOIN
    (
        SELECT instruction_id, MAX(basis_date) max_date
          FROM Estimates
         WHERE basis = 'ContractPrice'
         GROUP BY instruction_id
    ) q2 ON e.instruction_id = q2.instruction_id AND e.basis_date = q2.max_date
) p ON i.id = p.instruction_id
```

Output:

```
| ID |                              ADDRESS |     STATUS | CONTRACT_PRICE | CONTRACT_DATE | ESTIMATE_VALUE | ESTIMATE_DATE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 27 TAYLOR ROAD, ALBION PARK NSW 2527 | InProgress |         140000 |    2013-01-03 |         145000 |    2013-02-09 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19b76/9)** demo.

Comment: Thank you. Works well on a small subset of 'estimates'. However, our 'estimates' table contains 30k rows. I have done an EXPLAIN on the statement and the Achilles' heel is 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'. Is there perhaps a more efficient way to write the same SQL? Appreciate your time.

Comment: @TrentRenshaw You're welcome. I'm glad I could help :). Now did you try it on real data? What is the timing? There is nothing wrong with *'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'* on its own. Do you have all necessary indices on both tables? BTW 30k of rows is almost nothing nowadays.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, can you please send me an email trent.renshaw at objectst.com.au .. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the contract_price here?
You can try the below

```
select inst.id
     , inst.address
     , inst.status
     , est.basis_value as estimate_value
     , est.basis_date as estimate_date 
  from instructions inst
     , estimates est 
 where inst.id=est.instruction_id 
   and (est.basis='CustomerEstimate' or est.basis='ContractPrice') 
 order 
    by est.basis
     , est.basis_date desc;
```